# How to set up a highscore in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I have 5 high scores for a game I am making. Right now the scores are sorted and I have an if statement to stop taking scores once there are five. The problem is if the user has a new high score it won't be included into the database because of my if statement but I can't think of a way to fix this without restructuring what I already have. I have the logic that I want to use but I don't know how to implement it (inside the addProduct() method).

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "products.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME = "productname";

public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

//add a new row to the database
public void addProduct(Products product){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_PRODUCTS) <= 4){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
    else if(!(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_PRODUCTS) <= 4) && /* new score is a highscore */){
        //how to insert new high score into correct spot and delete last high score
    }
}

//code coming from MainActivity
public void addButtonClicked(String highscore1){
    Products product = new Products(highscore1);
    addProduct(product);
    updateDatabase();
}

//code coming from MainActivity
public void updateDatabase(){
        String dbString = databaseToString();
        MainActivity.productText.setText(dbString);
}

//delete a product from the database
public void deleteProduct(String productName){
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME + "=\"" + productName + "\";" );
}


//print out the database as a string
public String databaseToString(){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE 1";


    //Cursor point to location in your results
    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, null, null, null, null, COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME +" DESC");
    //Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    //Move to the first row in your results
    c.moveToFirst();

    while(!c.isAfterLast()){
        if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname")) != null){
            dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("productname"));
            dbString += "\n";
        }
        c.moveToNext();

    }


    db.close();
    return dbString;

}
```

}

Comment: Sort the resultset in descending order and take the top 5. All with one single query.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm: 
1. After sorting, query your db and determine if the new score is greater than any of the previous high scores 
2. If it is, add a flag to indicate it's a new high score. 
3. In your conditional logic (if statements), use the flag to determine if you have a new high score. 
4. If so, replace the new high score with the lowest score in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a new valid high score, you need to delete the older, smallest one.

The easiest way to do this is to always insert the new high score (even if it is smaller), and then delete all entries except the largest five ones. (This also handles the case where there are not yet five entries.)

```java
public void addProduct(Products product) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    try {
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COLUMN_PRODUCTNAME, product.get_productname());
            values.put("score", ...);
            db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, values);

            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM products WHERE _id NOT IN"+
                       " (SELECT _id FROM products ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5)",
                       null);

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }
    } finally {
        db.close();
    }
}
```

(To be able to change the database, you need to call get**Writable**Database(); and SQL tables are unordered, so there is no guarantee that you read the records in the same order you've written them, so you need to store the score in the table.)